# Django Imagefield and Legacy Database

Tags: html, django, database

I'm working with a legacy database that has images stored in a table. I want to use these images in `<img>` tags.

Do I need to write a script to read all the rows in the table, create a corresponding Django model, then save the model so that the image file is saved to the file system? Or is there a way to do this without iterating through all the old data?

**EDIT**

The actual images are stored as BLOBs in an Oracle 12c database.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information. What does it mean: "images stored in a table"? Are the images stored as binary data or only the filepaths are stored as strings? What kind of a database it is: MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Cezar. I have edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: In Django there is a `BinaryField`, although it isn't the recommended way for storing files. I'd go with with the approach you mentioned: retrieve all needed data from the legacy database, process it, and save it in a new created database, managed with Django models.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Cezar.